# Which versions of MySQL supports Tablespace creations?

Tags: mysql

I would like to apologize for my ignorance and sometimes I am unable to find the answer just by googling so I thought I would ask the question directly.  I am new to MySQL Workbench and I am attempting to Create Tablespaces and some other things and the warning keeps saying that it is not supported in InnoDB.  I understand that I required to set up an NDBCluster and are not sure how to set that up etc.

Does anyone know a good resource for MySQL Workbench?  The actual MySQL website just teaches however does not like to answer direct questions or obvious ones, the setup, what to do before or after just confusing...

Thank you all for the help as I greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Workbench is a front-end to a MySQL server. It's simply a user interface to the MySQL server's connection and query interface. There are many other front end programs. So, don't be confused by Workbench itself. You need simply to find tutorials on creating and administering databases in MySQL.

MySQL supports [general tablespaces](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/general-tablespaces.html) for InnoDB tables as of MySQL 5.7.6. Earlier versions require NDB tables and MySQL cluster.

If you're just starting to figure out MySQL and you're a developer rather than a database administrator, I suggest you avoid clustering. That's a system that doesn't make sense until you have either thousands of database connections, or tens of millions of rows, or both. To work with tablespaces, install a recent version of MySQL.

Comment: Well thank you kindly for the enlightenment!  That makes more sense.  I am a Junior DBA attempting to prepare a database for the company I am working with, and studying different types of software sometimes becomes confusing. Thank you again for your help!